# Where to submit this work with several unusual features?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, computational-geometry, computer-algebra, journals, proof-assistants

I appreciate that questions about where to submit are generally considered off-topic, but I hope that the unusual features of the present case may make it acceptable.

I have put a monograph on github at https://neilstrickland.github.io/genus2/, and also on the arxiv at https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06433. (The title is "Uniformization of embedded surfaces").

- It is 159 pages long, corresponding to about 15000 lines of LaTeX, mostly written in the traditional style with definitions, theorems and proofs.
- There are about 30000 lines of associated Maple code.  Anyone who wants to engage in a serious way with the monograph will probably want to download this code.
- A large fraction of the Maple code is used for semi-formal verification of proofs in the LaTeX document.  The project has a fairly systematic framework for this; it does not reach the same level of rigour as could be achieved with a proof assistant such as Coq or Isabelle, but it goes a long way in that direction.
- Another large fraction of the Maple code implements a network of related numerical algorithms.
- Documentation for the Maple code is provided as a family of HTML pages (visible from the URL above) with links between them.
- There are many coloured diagrams in the monograph, and colour is also used to distinguish between different kinds of text.  None of this is strictly essential for understanding, but it is certainly useful.

Can anyone suggest a good home where this work could be formally published?

Comment: since your work will anyway appear on arXiv, why not use an arXiv overlay journal, such as [SIGMA](http://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/) for "formal publication" ?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker an arXiv overlay is certainly a possibility.  This work seems out of scope for SIGMA, but not by a million miles.

Comment: Hi Neil. What's so sad is that you have to ask the question at all. Presumably you have created what you have created in order to benefit the mathematical community in some way, and the fact that you have created it already means the community can benefit. And now to placate your boss you need to get this "published" stamp of approval because of REF (UK government's way of ordering universities by publication quality, where publication is carefully defined). Sounds to me like it should be some sort of web resource, but the rules for REF won't allow for that!

Comment: One possibility is to publish the paper any conventional journal that accepts long papers (e.g., the Memoirs of the AMS) and then to make the code available separately. This may seem unsatisfactory because the code is not permanently archived, but permanent archival for a closed-source commercial software package like Maple is problematic anyway. As for colo[u]r, in my experience, most journals can accommodate it, though they may charge for it.

Comment: probably one can publish it as a book with a software component (Springer used to do such things). Presumably Maple might help here---for all other purposes Maple is a hassle, as it severely limits the number of people who would use the code you wrote. 
There are so many ways to achieve the same with something free and open-source (I know what happened with my Maple V code I wrote in my previous life - it just stopped working after some newer version of Maple, and I dumped it)...